# NodeJs - How to render EJS in a rendered EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

that's my idea: I want to load a rendered ejs file as the body of my main template ejs file. Is it possible?

My app.js:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('layout', {title: "Example title", body: _____________});
});
```

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
body: res.render('page1_body_content')
```

That would be my main-template-file (layout.ejs)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   <% (title) ? title : '' %>
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <%= body %>
 </body>
</html>
```

My 2nd file (page1_body_content.ejs) looks like this:

```html
<b>hallo</b>
```

The result should look like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Expample title
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <b>Hallo</b>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:-

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
var compiled = ejs.compile(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/page1_body_content.ejs', 'utf8'));
var html = compiled();

res.render('layout', {title: "Example title", body: html });
```

Update the body tag code to:-

```
<body>
    <%- body %>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks, it works so far. But the website does not show the "Hallo" as bold text. It's just "<b>Hallo</b>" and in the source code, It looks like this: &lt;b&gt;hallo&lt;/b&gt;

Comment: can you try var compiled = ejs.compile(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/page1_body_content.ejs'));

Comment: the second parameter ("utf8") seems to be needed. otherwise, it throws an error: "TypeError: this.templateText.replace is not a function
    at Template.generateSource (/Users/myname/myproject/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:573:25)"

Comment: Instead of <body>
  <%= body %>
 </body>

do this
<body>
 <%- body %>
 </body>

Comment: If the answer is correct, can you mark it as the right answer.Thanks